# Apache Commons Configurations2

Tags: java, apache-commons-config

I am using Apache commons configuration2 to read and write JSON configuration.

When I am trying to read a JSON file which contains any JSON Array with only one element.

```
{ 
   "default":{ 
      "recurrence_info":{ 
         "days":[ 
            "SUNDAY"
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

like in above  JSON "default.recurrence_info.days" is an array which contains only one element as "SUNDAY".

I am using below code to get configuration.

```
 //FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<FileBasedConfiguration>(
         JSONConfiguration.class).configure(new Parameters().hierarchical()
        .setExpressionEngine(engine)
         .setEncoding(CHAR_ENCODING).setThrowExceptionOnMissing(true))
         .setFileName(configFile)).getConfiguration();//
```

Here configFile is JSON file which contains above JSON.

When I try to get the value of "default.recurrence_info.days" , it is coming as string in place of array.

Finally after doing some debugging ,  What I understood If any JSON array contains only one element then "Apache commons configuration2" ignore the array and get the element as key(string)value(string) pair.

I want to get it as array .
Please let me know What change I can do to get it.

Comment: I have tried like  "configuration.getProperty(default.recurrence_info.days(0)) " and I got "SUNDAY" . But again If I will do  
 "configuration.setProperty(default.recurrence_info.days(0) , "SUNDAY")" , It will convert the JSON array to String key:value pair

Comment: Did you ever solve this?